# How can I set configuration properties for a SpringBootApplication that I start programmatically in a unit test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-boot-test

I have the following unit test in a SpringBoot 2.7.7 project.

I programmatically start the SpringBoot application so that I can catch an error I expect to be thrown on startup.

But the error is only thrown when a specific combination of `YAML` configuration properties are active, which is what I am trying to enable below.

Any ideas how I can reference the YAML and pass them along to the `springApplication` instance for startup?

```java
@ActiveProfiles("fail")
public class DatabaseMigratorFailTest {

  @Test
  public void testDatabaseMigrator() throws Exception {

    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(SpringBootApplication.class);
    
    //springApplication.setSources(); <- Unsure how to configure my application-fail.yml as a source of configuration values?

    springApplication.run();
    

    //assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
      //springApplication.run();
    //}).isInstanceOf(Exception.class);
  }
}
```

I have a YAML configuration file at the location:

```
src/test/resources/application-fail.yml
```

which contains various config values e.g:

```yaml
multi-tenancy:
  tenants:
    "001":
      configuration:
        database:
          jdbc-url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=001"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the profile manually for `application-fail.yml` to be loaded:

```java
SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(SpringBootApplication.class);
springApplication.setAdditionalProfiles("fail");

Assertions.assertThrows(
        Exception.class,
        () -> springApplication.run(),
        "Expected springApplication.run() to throw, but it didn't"
);
```

The `@ActiveProfiles("fail")` is not acted upon as the SpringBoot application is not automatically stood up for the test class.